# Lua .NET How to use the standard and third party libraries

Tags: c#, .net, lua, environment

I am using Lua inside C# WinForms application for GUI automation testing. I want to use the logging library http://www.keplerproject.org/lualogging/

But I don't know where to copy those logging library files and other standard lua files so that I can use the standard lua logging within the lua scripts.

I see something like LUA_PATH but still I don't understand how to make the lua packing strcuture without installing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried to use [LuaRocks](http://www.luarocks.org/).
Most libraries (including lualogging) are in the repositories, and the install is straightforward : luarocks install lualogging.

About the environment variables, you have to define two : LUA_PATH and LUA_CPATH.
If i'm correct, LUA_PATH is for the Lua libraries (i.e. mylib.lua), and LUA_CPATH is for the compiled binding to a native library (e.g. lsqlite3.so for the Sqlite binding).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does LUA_PATH supports multiple directories for example, in windows I should be able to mention LUA_PATH=C:\LUA51;C:\MyApp\Lua\Scripts;C:\Myapp\Lua\Lib;

Looks like LuaInterface has got issues with loading lua libraries when they reside outside path. Something needs to be hooked there

Comment: My environment variables are set this way :
LUA_PATH=/Users/jideel/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;?.lua
LUA_CPATH=/Users/jideel/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;?.so
So multiple paths separated by a ; seems to be supported, although i'didn't tried with Windows.

Comment: ;?.lua is meant to search lua files in the directory from wich the app has started.

Comment: the ?.lua or ?.so, ?.dylib, ?.dll is mandatory. You can't just specify the path alone.